# Remove the unwanted spaces but between the values

Tags: c++, string, c++11

```
Input -> Miguel de Cervantes,     Don Quixote,     Spain,    9.99,    1612,   The story follows a Hidalgo, Alonso Quixano, who proves that chivalry will in fact never die.
```

## Question

- How do I remove the spaces between the values but not inside of them?
- Example output: `Miguel de Cervantes,Don Quixote,Spain,.99,1612,The story follows a Hidalgo,Alonso Quixano,who proves that chivalry will in fact never die.`

#### Thank You

Comment: How about [`std::regex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace)?  `std::string result = std::regex_replace(input, std::regex re{" *, *"}, ",");`

Comment: @0x5453 that didn't work for me

Comment: DId any of the answers worked for you? If yes, then mark this thread as solved by accepting the answer.